# Replace all occurrences of a white space from string except the first occurrence using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, regex-negation

The input string having multiple whitespaces, and the result should have only one white space left, other whitespaces must be replaced with string.Empty

Input String: `+1 580 5691 234`  or  `(435) 772-5992`

Output String: `+1 5805691234`    or `+1 4357725992`

`Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\d]", string.Empty)` replaces all the whitespaces.

Comment: `[^\d]` also removes the first `+`.

Comment: ohh Yes it will :-)

Comment: Try `(?<!^\S*)\D` or `(?<!^\+?\d*)\D`. Please add either a set of more or less comprehensive test cases, or exact pattern requirements.

Comment: This fails for the Input : (435) 772-5992  , Special Chars must also be removed

Comment: So, `435 7725992` is the expected output for the string above?

Comment: Actually no, for the type of string (435) 772-5992 i add +1 at the start, then it should be like +1 4357725992, but input string is (435) 772-5992. I have to handle both scenarios with a single regex.

Comment: What's your actual requirement?  Is the goal to take any phone number and end up with: "+1 ######"?  Will you ALWAYS have "+1 " in the output string?

Comment: Yes! and it has been achieved by modifying your given regex to this "(?<!\+^?\d*)\D".   Thanks a lot

Comment: How about (at least) a comment to us spending time trying to come up with an answer for you. And if you found another solution, an explanation of how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it all within one line:

Remove the special characters as you like, get the position of the first space, remove spaces with your regex only in the substring after the first space.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely **must** do it with a single regex, this might be a solution for you:

Replace

```
^(?:\+1)?\D*(\d*)?\D*(\d*)?\D*(\d*)?\D*(\d*)?\D*(\d*)?$
```

with

```
+1 $1$2$3$4$5
```

Using 5 separate capture groups, it captures **only** digits, possibly separated by *non-digits*. If there are less than 5 digit groups, they're simply ignored.

Note that the optional preceding country code **isn't** captured either, and that the replace string always inserts it (back, if it existed).

This specific example limits the number of digit groups to 5, but could easily be expanded.

[Here at regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5c%2b1%29%3f%5cD*%28%5cd*%29%3f%5cD*%28%5cd*%29%3f%5cD*%28%5cd*%29%3f%5cD*%28%5cd*%29%3f%5cD*%28%5cd*%29%3f%24&i=+%2b1+580+5691+234%0d%0a%28435%29+772-5992&r=%2b1+%241%242%243%244%245&o=m).

[and illustrated here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9qLyJx/2).

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Regex engine can manage this with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\s+.*)\s+
```

It matches all blocks of whitespace which are preceded by at least one block of whitespace followed by some non-whitespace characters.

Using it as `Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=\s+.*)\s+", string.Empty)` on the string `+1 580 5691 234` produces the output `+1 5805691234`.